# My game crashes when I press a button (terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, crash

I'm making my game in Xcode 9.0 (beta version) And basically, I'm trying to get a button in the End Scene to present the Game Scene when it is clicked, but whenever I click the button, the game crashes and it says this in the console: `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.`

Can someone please help me!?

Below is the code I use.

```
import SpriteKit
```

class EndScene: SKScene {

```
var replayButton:SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    replayButton = self.childNode(withName: "replay") as! SKSpriteNode
    replayButton.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    replayButton.setScale(0.5)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if let location = touch?.location(in: self) {
        let nodesArray = self.nodes(at: location)

        if nodesArray.first?.name == "replay" {
            let transition = SKTransition.push(with: .right, duration: 1)
            let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
}
```

}

[My code for the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kicpO.png)

This is everything in the debug console when the app crashes:

2017-07-26 16:54:35.697622+0200 Sides[49264:5441087] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' texture:[ 'SidesBG1' (420 x 660)] position:{0, 0} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{2000, 2000} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae65c7b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106a80121 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aed7a45 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   SpriteKit                           0x00000001077b26a1 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 162
    4   SpriteKit                           0x00000001077b25de -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
    5   Sides                               0x000000010614d796 _T05Sides9GameSceneC7didMoveySo6SKViewC2to_tF + 7398
    6   Sides                               0x000000010614da2c _T05Sides9GameSceneC7didMoveySo6SKViewC2to_tFTo + 60
    7   SpriteKit                           0x0000000107779d2d -[SKScene _didMoveToView:] + 204
    8   SpriteKit                           0x0000000107799e00 -[SKView presentScene:transition:] + 347
    9   Sides                               0x0000000106156b42 _T05Sides8EndSceneC12touchesBeganys3SetVySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCSg4withtF + 1730
    10  Sides                               0x0000000106156dc8 _T05Sides8EndSceneC12touchesBeganys3SetVySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCSg4withtFTo + 104
    11  SpriteKit                           0x0000000107798181 -[SKView touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 1130
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107a5f998 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2130
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000107a61360 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000107a074d2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000108306384 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000108308eeb __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae093a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010adedc8f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aded23f __CFRunLoopRun + 1039
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010adecbb9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fd4d9e2 GSEventRunModal + 62
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001079eacb2 UIApplicationMain + 159
    23  Sides                               0x00000001061559d7 main + 55
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010bee4b95 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: can you add the stack trace?

Comment: ...and the description of the exception from the debug log.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: This is what it says in the debug log: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: You should put your actual code in the question and not an image of it.  Welcome to SO. Please take a look at this [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for best results when using this site.

Comment: You can found the trace in the debug console In bottom of XCode when your app is running.

Comment: This is everything in the debug console:

Comment: 2017-07-26 16:48:51.160451+0200 Sides[48965:5406187] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'SidesBG0' (417 x 657)] position:{0, 0} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{2000, 2000} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112b1cc7b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001108e4121 objc_exception_throw + 48

Comment: 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112b8ea45 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
 3   SpriteKit                           0x00000001116166a1 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 162
 4   SpriteKit                           0x00000001116165de -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
 5   Sides                               0x000000010ffb1996 _T05Sides9GameSceneC7didMoveySo6SKViewC2to_tF + 7398
 6   Sides                               0x000000010ffb1c2c _T05Sides9GameSceneC7didMoveySo6SKViewC2to_tFTo + 60

Comment: 7   SpriteKit                           0x00000001115ddd2d -[SKScene _didMoveToView:] + 204
 8   SpriteKit                           0x00000001115fdc3c -[SKView presentScene:] + 532
 9   Sides                               0x000000010ffbab5e _T05Sides8EndSceneC12touchesBeganys3SetVySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCSg4withtF + 1710
 10  Sides                               0x000000010ffbade8 _T05Sides8EndSceneC12touchesBeganys3SetVySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCSg4withtFTo + 104
 11  SpriteKit                           0x00000001115fc181 -[SKView

Comment: It's obvious your `GameScene` is reusing some nodes that are already presented, probably the background.

Comment: Oh, but what do I do then

Comment: @Sulthan that seems to fix the problem! :) But when I go back to the game scene, everything is too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it! It was because it was adding nodes that already existed, so I did removeFromParent to all my objects (except one, which were the enemies) and it worked(but the objects were still too big when I went back, so I did wrote this when transitioning to my EndScene: `let endScene = EndScene(fileNamed: "EndScene")
                endScene!.size = self.size
                endScene!.scaleMode = self.scaleMode`).

And wrote this when transitioning to my end scene: `let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
                gameScene!.size = self.size
                gameScene!.scaleMode = self.scaleMode` )

Huge thank you to @Sulthan!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating didMove to the following

```
    var replayButton: SKSpriteNode!
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    if (self.childNode(withName: "//replay") as? SKSpriteNode) != nil {
        replayButton = self.childNode(withName: "replay") as! SKSpriteNode
        replayButton.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        replayButton.setScale(0.5)

    }
}


override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if let location = touch?.location(in: self){
        let nodesArray = self.nodes(at: location)

        if nodesArray.first?.name == "replay"{
            let transition = SKTransition.push(with: .right, duration: 1)
            let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
}
```

I edited the code, check if this works without the crash and doing the action on the button.

Comment: It still says libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: @YohannesGobezie please update the "replay" to "//replay" in touchesEnded as well

Comment: When I do that the button won't do anything

Comment: @YohannesGobezie i edited the code, please check if that works.

Comment: It still crashes :(

Comment: @YohannesGobezie if you don't mind share your code via git and I can look into it. This way it's pretty difficult to detect why it is crashing there